# Replace pandas values as index to another array

Tags: pandas

Consider an array

```
a = np.array([5, 12, 56, 36])
```

and a pandas dataframe

```
b = pandas.DataFrame(np.array([1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2])
```

how does one replace the values on `b` by using its values as indexes for `a`, i.e., the intended value is:

```
c = pandas.DataFrame([12, 36, 5, 36, 12, 5, 56])
```

Can't quite figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using apply,

```
c = b.apply(lambda x: a[x])
```

Or by indexing the numpy array and passing the values to DataFrame,

```
c = pd.DataFrame(a[b[0].values])


    0
0   12
1   36
2   5
3   36
4   12
5   5
6   56
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(a[b.values])
`

Answer (score 1):

Let us try something different `Series.get`

```
pd.Series(a).get(b[0])
Out[57]: 
1    12
3    36
0     5
3    36
1    12
0     5
2    56
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

map can be used.

```
b.a.map({i:j for i,j in enumerate(a)})
0    12
1    36
2     5
3    36
4    12
5     5
6    56
Name: a, dtype: int64
```